# Titanium Image Compression for both Android and IOS

Tags: titanium

Need to compress the size of image before send image to the server for both android and ios.

Comment: you might want to try [image-factory module](https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.imagefactory)

Comment: thanks, i will try it, and revert back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried this module?

https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.imagefactory

here is the readme - https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.imagefactory/blob/stable/ios/documentation/index.md

but basic function is

`newBlob = ImageFactory.compress(blob, 0.25);`

Comment: i will try it, and revert back